# Sampling Frequency of a Rotational Sensor

Tags: sampling, frequency, sensor

[image]

In the picture above you can see a sensor I've been dealing with, called a "Caliper". This sensor arm simply passes over the pits or bumps on a disk rotating with a constant angular velocity $\omega$ and detects the angular change that occurs during this time with the encoder. This angular change is then converted into 'height ($h$)' information with the help of geometric relations and the height of the bump/pit is obtained.

What should the sampling frequency of the encoder be for this sensor to detect bumps/pits up to a minimum of height $h = 5 \,\texttt{mm}$ and a length of up to a minimum of $L = 20 \,\texttt{mm}$? (Assume the sensor arm tip is subjected to a linear velocity of $3 \,\texttt{m/s}$)

Comment: This looks very much like homework.  What have you tried so far, and how far have you gotten?  I.e., how long does it take for a feature of length 20mm take to go past your calipers?  What do you think that means with respect to the required sampling rate?

Comment: I'm actually considering the height rather than the length. Because that's the main purpose of the rotational sensor. Therefore, if the linear velocity is 3000 mm/s and the minimum h = 5 mm, the sampling rate will be 3000/5 = 600 1/s = 600 Hz. If the Nyquist theorem is used, I think a minimum 1.2 kHz sensor selection would be appropriate. I await your recommendations.